# Why does the stack size of an item in the inventory not change when used?

Tags: java

**Problem**:

I have a problem with my program where, when I want to decrease the stack size of an item in the inventory by 1, it doesn't change, when a certain button is pressed (e.g. 'space').

**Expected Result**:

What should happen is when 'space' is pressed, the stack size of the current item should change.

**Code**:

*UseItem()*:

```
if (coreEngine.getKeyManager().space) {
        useEnergy(Creature.DEFAULT_ENERGY_COST);
        inventory.useItem(inventory.getCurrentItem(), inventory.getCurrentSelection().getSlotID());
        CEMessage.printMessage("[stackSize]: " + inventory.getCurrentSelection().getCurrentStack());
        //stackSize of currentItem doesn't change when used
}
```

*inventory.useItem()*:

```
public void useItem(Item item, int slotIndex) {
    if (slotsList.get(slotIndex).getItem() == item) {
        slotsList.get(slotIndex).useItem(item); 
    }
}
```

*slot.useItem()*:

```
public void useItem(Item item) {
    currentStack = item.getStackSize();
    currentStack--;
}
```

*getCurrentItem()*:

```
public Item getCurrentItem() {
    return slotsList.get(currentSelection).getItem();
}
```

*getCurrentSelection()*:

```
public Slot getCurrentSelection() {
    return slotsList.get(currentSelection);
}
```

Comment: I am not sure about this line `currentStack--;` ... what types are `Item / currentStack`? Some sort of a number?

Comment: currentStack is an int value that contains the stack size of the current item. @hamena314

Comment: @Nick see my answer about `currentStack`, decrementing it like that won't change the value inside `item`.

Comment: @captainMan yes, I viewed your answer and it helped my understanding, however, the stack size didn't change with your implementation. I don't know why, unless, it has to do with my useItem() method inside inventory.java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to answer without a little bit more of tests.
in the following code :

```
public void useItem(Item item, int slotIndex) {
if (slotsList.get(slotIndex).getItem() == item) {
    System.out.println("reach here ?");
    slotsList.get(slotIndex).useItem(item); 
}}
```

If it does not print something on the console, it is surely because of `slotsList.get(slotIndex).getItem() == item`
and it would mean that you are comparing two object of the same type but with different references (not the same instance of the class).

---

EDIT : Answer

Here is the right answer then. There are two steps. First, you go to your Item class and you create a methode like this :

```
public boolean equals(Item itemToCompare)
```

. In that method, what you have to do is to compare the value of the common attribute of all the Item objects that differenciate them. For example, if one item has a name, you have to do :

```
public boolean equals(Item itemToCompare) {
 if (this.name.equals(itemToCompare.name))
    return true;
 else
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: Nothing gets printed when I use SOPL at that point of the program. Which means you are correct with the assumption that I may be comparing two of the same objects but with different references. Since that is the case, how do I properly compare the two objects?

Comment: I answered again with the idea of the method equals. If it works, please, vote for my answer (+1)

Comment: @Normal, can you please edit this one instead of posting a new one? It keeps the answers less cluttered :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is here.

```
public void useItem(Item item) {
    currentStack = item.getStackSize();
    currentStack--;
}
```

Try this

```
public void useItem(Item item) {
    currentStack = item.getStackSize();
    item.setStackSize(currentStack - 1);
}
```

Integers are "immutable" which means once they are made they can't be altered. When you do `i--` it's making a new Object or `int` value, not modifying the one that was there. So the `stackSize` value in `item` is still pointing at the old value.

---

Quick example of immutable versus mutable Objects

```
class MutableFoo {

    private Object bar;

    public void setBar(Object bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public Object getBar() {
        return bar;
    }
}
```

In the above you can modify `MutableFoo` by using `setBar`.

```
class ImmutableFoo {

    private Object bar;

    ImmutableFoo(Object bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public Object getBar() {
        return bar;
    }
}
```

In here however there is no way to modify `ImmutableFoo`, we can only use the constructor to set `bar`'s value so if we want to "modify" an `ImmutableFoo` we need to make a new one.

It's the difference between

```
Object bar = ...
MutableFoo mFoo = new MutableFoo();
mFoo.setBar(bar);
Object newBar = ...
mFoo.setBar(newBar);
```

and

```
Object bar = ...
ImmutableFoo iFoo = new ImmutableFoo(bar);
Object newBar = ...
iFoo = new ImmutableFoo(newBar); // Have to make a new ImmutableFoo.
```

Comment: Thanks for the well explained answer!! However, after changing the code to what you said with,  item.setStackSize(currentStack - 1); The stack size doesn't change.

Comment: Do you think it may have something to do w/ my useItem() method inside inventory.java?

Comment: @Nick I actually think it's also the other answer about using `==`. `==` checks if they are pointing to the *same* thing Object in memory. `String s` = "hey"`, `String s2 = "hey"`, doing `s1 == s2` will be `false`, but `s1.equals(s2)` will work. You should implement a method to check if the items are equal or not *or* double check that they are actually the same thing, not copies of each other.